# Elasticsearch: when inserting a record to index I don't want to create an index mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Elasticsearch default behavior when inserting a document to an index, is to create an index mapping if it's not exist. 
I know that I can change this behavior on the cluster level using this call

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
    "persistent": {
        "action.auto_create_index": "false" 
    }
}
```

but I can't control the customer's elasticsearch. 
I'm asking is there a parameter which I can send with the index a document request that will tell elastic not to create the index in case it doesn't exist but to fail instead?

Comment: You want to fail if index isn’t there? Or if mapping isn’t there?

Comment: If the index isn't there

Comment: Do you have Xpath ? Maybe the user right section could help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you couldn’t change cluster settings or settings in *elasticsearch.yml*, I’m afraid it’s not possible, since there are no special parameters during POST/PUT of the documents.

Another possible solution could be to create an API level, which will prevent going to Elasticsearch completely, if there is no such index.

There is an [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23745) on Github, that is proposing to set `action.auto_create_index` to **false** by default, but unfortunately, I couldn’t see if there is any progress on it.

Comment: This is what I do. But it probably slows the performance to check for index existence every time